# move the grid origin to object origin

Tags: transform-orientation

How can I move the grid origin to the origin of an object?
Instead of relocating all objects in order to have the origin of one particular object positioned at the origin of the grid?

I'd like to snap to a grid within a local object.

Comment: grid within an object? Can you make a screenshot where you manually did (or almost) did that?

Comment: I don't think it is possible by default. Any reason why don't move all objects.

Comment: You want to keep the objects as they are because it is easy to loose one when partial viewing. Moving the underlying grid makes it easy to virtually subdivide different size and shape objects. It is related to moving the origin of an object for a particular operation vs moving the all objects to the origin, perform the transformation, then move everything back.

Comment: Partial viewing is not a problem if you can perform Select All (but it can be an issue for locked or hidden objects, OK). Yet not sure if I got the point - for transformations you can use 3D Cursor as Pivot Point, right? BTW to Snap to Grid from Objects Origin it is by default. Its just not represented by lines. https://imgur.com/qtQNX0Y

Comment: it is related to the ability to move the 3d cursor. You can place it anywhere and have objects snap to it etc. I'd like to have the option to have the origin of the grid at the 3d cursor.